# Bad HD video deinterlacing processing

Tags: video, mplayer, ubuntu-unity, vdpau

I have Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit with Unity. My system configuration is:

CPU: Core 2 Quad Q6600 (2.4 GHz)
RAM: 8192 Mb DDR2 Kingston
Video: Palit GeForce GTX 260 216 SP, and my screen resolution is 1680x1050.

I also have Window 7 Ulitimate installed, and I can see the same files in Media Player Classic without any horizontal lines.

I've installed vdpau driver, NVIDIA drivers 304.51, and MPlayer 2 (within SMPlayer). I've disabled "Sync to VBlank" option in CCSM (because in other way, by default, MPlayer process use about 50-60 percents of my processor load), tried to swich between different deinterlace options in SMPlayer, used "-vc ffh264vdpau,ffmpeg12vdpau" (without quotes) parameters for MPlayer, switched to "Ubuntu 2D", but, finally, have no results.

Any suggestions? How must I to set up MPlayer?

Comment: Your host is is windows 7, and your guest is Ubuntu?
Have you tried VLC / YouTube Flash? Are you sure this is a deinterlace problem? most videos downloaded from the internet  are progressive. 

Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Why do you think I use a virtual machine?

Comment: hah, my bad. VMware also has a feature called unity, I thought you were talking about that.

Answer (score -2):

VLC has different deinterlacing-modes. Be sure to try them all, as not all modes work with all types of video-sources...

Comment: The OP is using MPlayer though.

Comment: VLC also has support for Ubuntu (and Windows, Mac Os X and other Linux distros.) [Download page link](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html#download)